# Implementing Sitecore Search Using Lucene

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

I am in the process of trying to get Lucene search to work with my Sitecore installation. 
I have tried following the example listed in the [Sitecore guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_search_and_indexing_sc60-65-a4.pdf) (sections 2.1 thru 2.2.2).

After adding the LuceneSearchBox and clicking on the control's search button, I receive the following error:

```
Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

This is what appears in the address bar, in the event it provides some helpful clues:

```
mytestsite/sitecore/service/nolayout.aspx?item=%2fstandard_items%2fsearch_results&layout=%7b00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7d&device=Default
```

Should I be doing something with the LuceneSearchResults control? The guide does not mention doing anything with the LucenSearchResult control.

Notes:

1. I am using this on a web site that I have created, not the "Office Core Web site" listed in the guide.
2. I am running Sitecore 6.3.1

Comment: Realized that the module created a Standard_Items folder with Search_Results content template inside. Had to create a new item inside this folder named Search_Results and add the LuceneSearchResults sublayout to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way of working with Lucene in Sitecore is by using the Advanced Database Crawler project.  Alex Shyba, a Solution Architect at Sitecore, put together a C# class library that wraps the native Lucene functionality and adds helper methods to make it easy to use Lucene to search for content in Sitecore.

There's two parts to this project: 1. Advanced Database Crawler, 2. Searcher.

Here's the URL, http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html?m=1.